# How to filter XML from event viewer with Select-Xml, -Xml and -XPath

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I want to be able to filter XML from event viewer with XPath.

First, I grab the event:

```
$events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName="Security"; id=4624} | Select -First 2
[xml]$xmlEvent = $events[0].ToXml()
```

Now I want to get events with logon type 2.

One method that works fine is by:

```
($xmlEvent.Event.EventData.Data | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "LogonType"}).'#text' -eq 2
```

But I want to be able to do it with XPath because I want to understand how to work with it.

This is what I tried at first:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Select-Xml -Xml $xmlEvent -XPath "*"

Node  Path        Pattern
----  ----        -------
Event InputStream *
```

I received the event which is good, but now I want to add the filter.
I tried:

```
Select-Xml -Xml $xmlEvent -XPath "*/Event[EventData[@Name='LogonType'] = 2]"
```

There was no output at all, I also tried the following and didn't receive any output:

```
Select-Xml -Xml $xmlEvent -XPath "/Event[EventData[@Name='LogonType'] = 2]"
Select-Xml -Xml $xmlEvent -XPath "/Event"
Select-Xml -Xml $xmlEvent -XPath "//Event"
Select-Xml -Xml $xmlEvent -XPath "*/Event"
```

Reference I used:
[Understanding XML and XPath](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/06/06/understanding-xml-and-xpath/)
[Search XML files with PowerShell using Select XML](https://www.petri.com/search-xml-files-powershell-using-select-xml)

Comment: You need to pass an explicit namespace reference for it to work: `Select-Xml -Xml $xmlEvent -XPath '//Evt:Event' -Namespace @{Evt=$xmlEvent.Event.xmlns}`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen great and now how can I combine a filter. I tried `Select-Xml -Xml $xmlEvent -XPath "//Evt:Event/[EventData[@Name ='LogonType'] = 2]" -Namespace @{Evt=$xmlEvent.Event.xmlns}` but it writes me "Select-Xml : Expression must evaluate to a node-set."

Comment: `EventData` -> `Evt:EventData` should do it :-)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen looking better with `Select-Xml -Xml $xmlEvent -XPath "//Evt:EventData" -Namespace @{Evt=$xmlEvent.Event.xmlns}` but how can I search inside ? I tried: `-XPath "//Evt:EventData[[@Name='LogonType'] = 2]"`but it writes me again "Expression must evaluate to a node-set"

Comment: I think the path expression you're looking for is more like`//Evt:Data[@Name = 'LogonType'] and . = 2]`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I tried `Select-Xml -Xml $xmlEvent -XPath "//Evt:Data[@Name='LogonType'] = 2" -Namespace @{Evt=$xmlEvent.Event.xmlns}` it still writes me the same error with the expression. Also with `"//Evt:Data[@Name='LogonType'] and . = 2"` it doesn't work. I tried `"//Evt:Data[@Name='LogonType'] = 2"` => same thing